# Add UILabel to UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

I have Multiple `UITextView`'s that I have created with a for-loop programmatically. I'm trying to add a `UILabel` to the upper left corner of each `UITextView` also.
How can I do that?

My `UITextView` code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPos, 375,height)];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]]; //set different property like this
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:204.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    textView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    textView.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
    textView.editable=NO;

    [CommentScrooll addSubview:textView ];
    // CommentScroll Is the name of my viewcontroller
    yPos += (height + padding);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-c code:-

```
UILabel *cust_Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Your_X, Your_Y, Your_Width,Your_Height)];
cust_Label.text=@"Your Text";
[textView addSubview: cust_Label];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never added a `UILabel` to a `UITextView` before but I just tested this and it worked. This is the general idea:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
label.text = "My Label"
textView.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: ca you write it in Objective-c please?